# Issue with a Regex for 2 scenarios 1234-12345 or 1234-12345A it should allow only these two scenarios

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried with this below code but this isn't working for me

```
$('form input[name="email"]').blur(function () {
    var text = $(this).val();
var re = /^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}[A-Ba-b]{1}|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5})/;

if (re.test(text)) {
    $('.msg').hide();
    $('.success').show();
} 
else {
    $('.msg').hide();
    $('.error').show();
}
});
```

Comment: Why not `^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}[A-Ba-b]?)`? Also the `^` at beginning mean that it will only catch results at start of line. If you are searching for these codes inside a text, remove it.

Comment: What is not working ? only problem i can see is if you want to match complete string, then you should have a `$` anchor at the end of pattern

Comment: @EliasSoares the `?` at the end means that any character will be caught, eg `...12345C`

Comment: $ at the end worked thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, it mean that the expression under [] might or not be present.

Comment: Exactly my point.